# How Can I Debug a Mutex Deadlock in a Qt Event handler (QDBusConnectionPrivate)

Tags: c++, qt

I am running across an intermittent deadlock in initialization of my Qt program, while it's relatively idle and in the event loop.

I confirmed this was a futex_wait by using strace, and I always see an entry like this for the main thread:
[pid  1768] futex(0x7f28f400aecc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL

I found out that I could add a Qt event filter, and therefore log events as they are processed from the main thread. Here's a snippet for that:

```
bool ActivityEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev){
VLOG(5) << "inspecting event " << obj << " name " << obj->objectName().toStdString() << " class " << obj->metaObject()->className() << " eventType " << ev->type();

  if (VLOG_IS_ON(5))
  {
    if (ev->type() == QEvent::MetaCall)
    {
        if (QString(obj->metaObject()->className()).contains("QDBusConnectionPrivate")
        {
            VLOG(5) << "Dumping object data";
            obj->dumpObjectInfo();
            obj->dumpObjectTree();
        }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And examining my logging, the freeze always is preceded by these lines:

```
I0614 17:18:27.928889  1812 ActivityEventFilter.cpp:19] inspecting event 0x7fde200144c0 name  class QDBusConnectionPrivate eventType 43
I0614 17:18:27.928901 1812 ActivityEventFilter.cpp:28] Dumping object data
```

There is no output from the object info or from the object tree.

I am not consciously using DBus anywhere in my application, so I'm looking to find a way to track down who is calling it to see if it can be prevented, but without the objectInfo, I don't know where to start.

I found two Qt bug reports:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42189

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51648

The first looks like the problem, but it appears all the resolutions went into Qt 5.4.0. (I'm using Qt 5.4.1)
The second looks a bit different.

Comment: I would just see the stack on the deadlocked thread. BTW "Dumping ..." printout is always there and then it locks. Either that VLOG or obj->dumpObjectInfo/Tree?